# insert a new department into the DEPARTMENTS table using pl/sql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

Rather than printing the department number add 10 to it and use it as the department number of the new department.
Use a SQL*Plus substitution variable to enter the department name: EDUCATION.  (Use the ACCEPT command to input the department name into the variable)
Display the details of the new department

```
   VARIABLE g_dept_name VARCHAR2(30)
   VARIABLE g_dept_id NUMBER

  DECLARE 
   v_dept_name departments.dept_name%TYPE:= 'Education';
   v_dept_id NUMBER;

 BEGIN
 SELECT MAX(department_id)+ 10
 INTO v_dept_id
  FROM departments;
 INSERT INTO departments (department_id, department_name,manager_id, location_id)
 VALUES (v_dept_id, v_dept_name,'276', '2100' );
  END;
    /
```

I tried this code and it didn't work it said usually a pl/sql complication error

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample table; apparently, you'd enter ID = 50. Just note that using `MAX + 1` is **wrong** in most cases. It'll be OK in a single-user environment, but - in a multi-user one, sooner or later two (or more) people will fetch the same MAX and either will only one of them succeed to insert such a value (the first one who commits) and others will fail because of possible primary key / unique constraint, or everyone will succeed, but you'll get duplicates.

```
SQL> select * from departments;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAM MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- -------------- ---------- -----------
           10 ACCOUNTING           1000         200
           20 RESEARCH             1000         200
           30 SALES                1000         200
           40 OPERATIONS           1000         200
```

Let's accept department name:

```
SQL> ACCEPT v_dept_name CHAR PROMPT 'Enter department name: '
Enter department name: EDUCATION
```

PL/SQL code that uses previously entered name as a substitution variable:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_dept_id  NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT MAX (department_id) + 10 INTO v_dept_id FROM departments;
  5
  6     INSERT INTO departments (department_id,
  7                              department_name,
  8                              manager_id,
  9                              location_id)
 10          VALUES (v_dept_id,
 11                  '&v_dept_name',
 12                  '276',
 13                  '2100');
 14  END;
 15  /
old  11:                 '&v_dept_name',
new  11:                 'EDUCATION',

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from departments where department_name = 'EDUCATION';

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAM MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- -------------- ---------- -----------
           50 EDUCATION             276        2100

SQL>
```

---

> it said usually a pl/sql **complication** error

You **must** be kidding.